# Apache CXF + Spring: Generating a Simple Client

Tags: java, web-services, spring, cxf

I've started learning the Apache CXF with Spring. First of all, I've tried to create a simple client/server model.

*The server-side is:*
**service.HelloWorld.java**

```
@WebService
public interface HelloWorld {
  String sayHi(String text);
}
```

**service.HelloWorldImpl.java**

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "service.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {
   public String sayHi(String text) {
     return "Hello, " + text;
   }
}
```

*The client-side is:*
**client.Client.java**
    public class Client {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new  String[] {"cxf-client-servlet.xml"});
          HelloWorld client = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("client");
          System.out.println(client.sayHi("Batman"));
    }
}
```

**cxf-client-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
    http://cxf.apache.org/schema/jaxws.xsd">

<bean id="client" class="service.HelloWorld" factory-bean="clientFactory" factory-method="create"/>

<bean id="clientFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="service.HelloWorld"/>
    <property name="address" value="http://localhost:8080/services/HelloWorld"/>
</bean>
```

The problem is: to make the client work I've had to add service.HelloWorld (package + interface) to the clients's project. I've heard that before using a service I need to generate a stub. So it's confusing for me. So that, what is the correct approach and what is the best practice (may be it is better to use some contract-first approach or suchlike)? Later, I want to add WS-Security, so I need a strong background =)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing code-first WS development then it is fine to distribute the interface and give it to the client. <del>I believe `@WebService` is not needed (?) on the interface (only implementation), so the client does not have dependencies on this annotation.</del>

Even if you are doing code-first web-services, you may still download the WSDL document generated for you by Apache CXF and give it to the client instead. With this approach (which is considered more mature, not to mention it can be used on different platforms like .NET) the client has to generate the stubs (using tool like `wsdl2java`). This process will essentially create very similar client interface automatically.

That's one of the reasons why so many people prefer contract-first development - the same WSDL is used to generate client-side stubs and server-side WS implementation. This limits the scope of (accidental) incompatibilites.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can the service distribute the interface?

Comment: So you suggest not to use JaxWsProxyFactoryBean?

Comment: @WebService annotation is needed - I've checked =)

Comment: @Dmitry: you can either give the client a Java interface you are using on the server or give him WSDL. In that case the client is responsible for **generating** the client interface from WSDL. In both cases `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean` is used to create a proxy that implements that interface.

Comment: Oh, I see. And if I give it a WSDL, how to use it? Could you, please, give a code snippet or some article's reference?

Comment: @Dmitry: Sure, [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) is an article about `wsdl2java` with Apache CXF. The workflow is simple - this tool generates Java classes for all elements declared using XML Schema and Java interface for every endpoint. Apache CXF client code knows what to do with them.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple spring configuration like this for client side -

```
<jaxws:client id="mywebServiceClient"
    serviceClass="com.saurzcode.TestService"
    address="http://saurzcode.com:8088/mockTestService">

    <jaxws:binding>
        <soap:soapBinding version="1.2" mtomEnabled="true" />
    </jaxws:binding>
</jaxws:client>
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="com.saurzcode.ws.caller.SoapHeaderInterceptor" />
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

Ignore the Interceptor if you don't need it.

More details in this [post.](http://saurzcode.in/2014/05/08/adding-header-to-soap-request-using-cxf-2/)

Comment: How to inject this client into a bean?

Comment: @MarcinErbel Can you elaborate what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Ok i just had problems in my mvn repository. I thought that injecting Client inside bean is much more complicated. Nvm, but thanks for an answer.