# Apache CXF + Spring: Simple Certificate Authentication

Tags: java, web-services, spring, cxf

I've started learning the Apache CXF with Spring. First of all, I've created a simple client/server model: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032960/apache-cxf-spring-generating-a-simple-client)

Now I'm trying to use a simple certificate authentication. So that I've changed the configuration files (for the server and client):
**cxf-servlet.xml**:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<jaxws:endpoint
    id="helloWorld"
    implementor="service.HelloWorldImpl"
    address="/HelloWorld">

    <jaxws:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature"/>
    </jaxws:features>
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
       <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor"/>
       <ref bean="WSS4JInInterceptor"/>
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
</jaxws:endpoint>

<bean id="WSS4JInInterceptor"  class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="action" value="Signature"/>
            <entry key="passwordCallbackRef">
                <ref bean="passwordCallback"/>
            </entry>
            <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="server_sign.properties"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="passwordCallback" class="service.PasswordCallbackHandler" />
```

**server_sign.properties**:

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=keyStorePassword
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file=publicstore.jks
```

**cxf-client-servlet.xml**:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
    http://cxf.apache.org/schema/jaxws.xsd">

<bean id="client" class="service.HelloWorld" factory-bean="clientFactory" factory-method="create"/>

<bean id="clientFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="service.HelloWorld"/>
    <property name="address" value="http://localhost:8080/services/HelloWorld"/>
    <property name="outInterceptors">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor"/>
            <ref bean="WSS4JOutInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="WSS4JOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
    <property name="properties">
        <map>
            <entry key="action" value="Signature"/>
            <entry key="user" value="ws-client" />
             <entry key="passwordCallbackRef">
                <ref bean="passwordCallback"/>
            </entry>
            <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="client_sign.properties"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="passwordCallback" class="client.PasswordCallbackHandler" />
```

The client is working perfectly. It uses it's PasswordCallbackHandler. The problem is the server doesn't seem to use its PasswordCallbackHandler. I've run the server in a debug mode, but it doesn't go to this class. Can anybody, please, explain, what do I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**PROGRESS:**

1. if you try to provide a request from a user, which certificate is not in the server's keystore, the error is raised ("No certificates for user ws-client1 were found for signature")
2. from [the resource](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/JBoss_WS_CXF_User_Guide/ch11s02.html): "As you can see in the jbossws-cxf.xml file above, a keystore password callback handler is also configured; while the properties file has the password for the keystore, this callback handler is used to set password for each key (it has to match the one used when each key was imported in the store)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after some research in the source code of wss4j I've realized, that there is no callback handler in the WSS4JInInterceptor in the case of the Signature action (only).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to add `<entry key="action" value="UsernameToken Signature" />` to both server and client contexts (otherwise you have only sign action). Also for client `<entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />` might be necessary (I am not sure what is default: plaintext or digest, I suppose the last one).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But I only want to use the signature mechanism. Is it possible?

Comment: For the password, it seems that the callback must anyway be in use. But that's of course IMHO )

Comment: Your original questions was "Why `PasswordCallbackHandler` is not called". What is what I've put into my answer: you missed the appropriate action. If you need only signature, then you leave only `Signature` action and can safely remove `passwordCallbackRef` and `user` entries from both contents. I hope you understand that  `PasswordCallbackHandler` is called by CXF framework to ask the application, if user and password are valid, and that is nothing to do with signing. The password for your keystore should be defined in `client/server.properties` correspondingly.

Comment: There is no way to remove the "user" property, because the "Empty username for specified action" error raises (action=Signature).

Comment: The "passwordCallbackRef" is also required (but only on the client's side), because the "application provided null or empty password" error is raised.

Comment: Yes, you're right: user/password need to be provided for client (I've checked [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html#WS-Security-Signing)). That is new to me each entry in keystore can be protected with password separately. Even in this case why can't one add a key without a password? But key alias is needed, as keystore may contain many keys.

Comment: I far as I'm concerned it is possible to add a key with the same password as for the keystore. In every tutorial the server has its passwordCallbackHandler. But I can't find how to make it work...

Comment: You don't need password on the server: public keys are stored in public store and the key will be selected automatically.