# Creating a wrapper REST service for a SOAP webservice using jboss FUSE

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I am trying to create a REST webservice wrapper for existing SOAP based webservices. Has anyone implemented it using JBOSS Fuse? Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: I have built a restful service and capability to call a SOAP service fro within that REST service .But I am looking to transform a REST payload to a SOAP one on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a JBOSS FUSE transformation suite which can be used to map JSON to XML or vice versa.This is part of the JBOSS tools and a link to the tutorial

[XML_TO_JSON Tutorial](http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2015-06-01-so-you-want-to-transform-part-1.html)

This can be used along the camel route from the rest webservice to the soap webservice.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a Rest endpoint and SOAP client using CXF and use a service bean on the Rest endpoint to forward calls to the SOAP client.

You can do this completely with a Java bean, CXF and blueprint/spring. No Camel required.

Take a look here:

1. Rest service endpoint configuration: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-Blueprint
2. Take a look at the second answer here for generating a SOAP client: [Apache CXF + Spring: Generating a Simple Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032960/apache-cxf-spring-generating-a-simple-client)

Use blueprint/spring to inject the generated soap client into the bean that implements the Rest server endpoint. Then simply call the soap client there.

If you want to increase performance you could add server side caching to the rest endpoint: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-advanced-features.html#JAX-RSAdvancedFeatures-Server-sidecaching

Comment: Thanks! I have actually tried something like this and it works, but I have to code up each time a new SOAP Web Service needs to be supported. I am looking for a framework which can just transform the rest payload to a soap payload.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to go from REST i.e. something like JSON to SOAP? Well you need to perform some mapping right. Either do this via POJO to CXF or use Velocity or some other template marker and perform the mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.